# How can I import a csv file into Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have not got a clue about this one and hopefully you can help with some utility code somewhere.

I have a comma delimeted file and I need to import into exce?

Any ideas?
This is for a windows form application in c# 3.5.
Thanks

Comment: Excel will directly open a CSV file as a spreadsheet. So I assume you mean that you need an application that imports a CSV to fill in an existing spreadsheet that uses that data for calculations or graphing or something of that sort. Could you add more detail to your question?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587325/c-excel-import-data-from-csv-into-excel

Comment: Hi,the process has to be automatic.
User press button and open a file and this is converted to excel
without open excel to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look into OLE Automation. You would instantiate and control an Excel application object from your C# code.