# Convert CSV into XLS

Tags: c#, csv, xls

I'm working in a web application separated in blocks and I'm getting a CSV object from a work mate of mine which I must convert into XLS to be passed into an Excel Processor they built.
This CSV object is delimited by the character ";".

What I'd like to know is how I can convert the CSV object into XLS programatically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be easy for you to convert the CSV object into an array of arrays of strings and then do like in the following example (you'll need to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel):

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.ActiveSheet;

var CsvContent = new string[][]
{
    new string[] {"FirstName", "UserName", "PostCode", "City"},
    new string[] {"John", "Smith", "4568", "London"},
    new string[] {"Brian", "May", "9999", "Acapulco"}
};

for (int i = 0; i < CsvContent.Length; i++)
{
    string[] CsvLine = CsvContent[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < CsvLine.Length; j++)
    {
        sheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = CsvLine[j];
    }
}

workBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\fromCsv.xls");
workBook.Close();
```

Comment: I'm going to try to follow your example and I'll give you feedback in a while, thanks.

Comment: how can you do the csv converting to array of strings?

Comment: @user65165 If your csv contains only non escaped characters, you can use string.Split otherwise you can use one of the csv parser libraries available

Answer (score 2):

Does the output need to be in the legacy XLS format? If [XLSX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLSX) is acceptable, [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is a great .NET library for writing spreadsheets. The older [excellibrary](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary) can produce XLS files.

Only a few lines of code should be necessary for parsing the CSV file (just be careful of double quotation marks) and writing the output spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, one of the requirements is that the XLS format is passed.

Comment: In that case, it might be worth looking at excellibrary, which is an older library that writes XLS files. http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a 3rd party library to create the XLS file, and the other is to use COM interop to manipulate Excel into opening the CSV file and save it as XLS.

Comment: Is there any example on the web about your 2nd option?

Answer (score 0):

Would this [C# Excel import data from CSV into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587325/c-excel-import-data-from-csv-into-excel) help?  It seems to address what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public void Convert_CSV_To_Excel()
    {

        // Rename .csv To .xls
        System.IO.File.Move(@"d:\Test.csv", @"d:\Test.csv.xls");

        var _app = new Excel.Application();
        var _workbooks = _app.Workbooks;

        _workbooks.OpenText("Test.csv.xls",
                                 DataType: Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                                 TextQualifier: Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
                                 ConsecutiveDelimiter: true,
                                 Semicolon: true);
        // Convert To Excle 97 / 2003
        _workbooks[1].SaveAs("NewTest.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel5);

        _workbooks.Close();
    }
```