# C# convert csv to xls (using existing csv file)

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, converters

i believe here are lot a discussion with this matter.
but i read all post and try but it never work with c#.
my goal is simple that i have existing csv file.
just want convert exel file and done.
many people said that using spire.xls something but i believe MS .office.interop.excel could handle it.

[Converting Excel File From .csv To .xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732343/converting-excel-file-from-csv-to-xlsx)

i read above issue and this is same as my problem.
but above code not work in my PC.. do i need to import other dll to use this.
i just copy code from that site. copy again below...

currently im using Lib as MS.office.interop.excel   and    MS.office.interop.core

```
Application app = new Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\testcsv.csv", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,               Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wb.SaveAs(@"C:\testcsv.xlsx", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing,    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wb.Close();
app.Quit();
```

here are lot a error. modify code is below and now im only using MS.office.interop.excel   and    MS.office.interop.core in my reference.
it looks like i need to use another dll file.
anyway i did follow that code and make new code.
it reduce error but i don't know this is correct approach.
below is what i tried now.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

System.Globalization.CultureInfo oldCI = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\testcsv.csv", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\testcsv.xlsx",    XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
xlWorkBook.Close();
```

and here are error message

> Error  3  The name 'XlFileFormat' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Users\jochoi\Desktop\joseph_BT_전류_code\DC_Test -
>   ver01\DC_Test\DC.cs   528 54  DC_Test
>   Error 4   The name 'XlSaveAsAccessMode' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\Users\jochoi\Desktop\joseph_BT_전류_code\DC_Test -
>   ver01\DC_Test\DC.cs   528 142 DC_Test
>   Error 4   No overload for method 'Close' takes '0'
>   arguments C:\Users\jochoi\Desktop\joseph_BT_전류_code\DC_Test -
>   ver01\DC_Test\DC.cs   525 13  DC_Test

my goal is just grab exist csv file and just change to excel file.
does anyone has other solution because that answer is not work in my pc. (c#)

Comment: please post the actual error you're getting

Comment: Yes, i add more detail in my question and also add error messages....

Comment: you could use the library from the question you've linked to. Or you could try the approach used in the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781478/convert-csv-into-xls

Answer (score 50, accepted):

COM Interop is not the best solution, especially if you're planning to run your code in a [server environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Another approach is to use components fit for that purpose.
I've used [EEplus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus) and it does its dirty job. <del>It has a LGPL licence but the author does not seem to be to [worried](https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/208363) about you using it in your commercial product.</del>

Just install the nuget package:

```
Install-Package EPPlus
```

and use this code:

```
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string csvFileName = @"FL_insurance_sample.csv";
        string excelFileName = @"FL_insurance_sample.xls";

        string worksheetsName = "TEST";

        bool firstRowIsHeader = false;

        var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Delimiter = ',';
        format.EOL = "\r";              // DEFAULT IS "\r\n";
        // format.TextQualifier = '"';

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFileName)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(csvFileName), format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium27, firstRowIsHeader);
            package.Save();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You can configure the structure of you CVS using `ExcelTextFormat`.

I've tested it with some data taken from [here](http://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/).

Some more samples can be found [here](https://github.com/ylatuya/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample9.cs).

**UPDATE:**

Another option is to read the CSV file yourself as a text file:

```
private IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsv(string fileName, char delimiter = ';')
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.UTF8).Select(a => a.Split(delimiter));
    return (lines);
}
```

and use other open-source projects such as [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) or [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). 
**NPOI** and **ClosedXML** cannot read **CSV** and do the conversion but using the function `ReadCsv` you can do it yourself.

*Both these projects have permissive licences.*

**NPOI Conversion:**

```
private static bool ConvertWithNPOI(string excelFileName, string worksheetName, IEnumerable<string[]> csvLines)
{
    if (csvLines == null || csvLines.Count() == 0)
    {
    return (false);
    }

    int rowCount = 0;
    int colCount = 0;

    IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ISheet worksheet = workbook.CreateSheet(worksheetName);

    foreach (var line in csvLines)
    {
    IRow row = worksheet.CreateRow(rowCount);

    colCount = 0;
    foreach (var col in line)
    {
        row.CreateCell(colCount).SetCellValue(TypeConverter.TryConvert(col));
        colCount++;
    }
    rowCount++;
    }

    using (FileStream fileWriter = File.Create(excelFileName))
    {
       workbook.Write(fileWriter);
       fileWriter.Close();
    }

    worksheet = null;
    workbook = null;

    return (true);
}
```

**ClosedXML Conversion:**

```
private static bool ConvertWithClosedXml(string excelFileName, string worksheetName, IEnumerable<string[]> csvLines)
{
    if (csvLines == null || csvLines.Count() == 0)
    {
    return (false);
    }

    int rowCount = 0;
    int colCount = 0;

    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
    {
    using (var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetName))
    {
        rowCount = 1;
        foreach (var line in csvLines)
        {
        colCount = 1;
        foreach (var col in line)
        {
            worksheet.Cell(rowCount, colCount).Value = TypeConverter.TryConvert(col);
            colCount++;
        }
        rowCount++;
        }

    }
    workbook.SaveAs(excelFileName);
    }

    return (true);
}
```

If someone is interested there's a [sample project](https://github.com/Leftyx/ConvertCsvToExcel/tree/master) on github with some test for performances comparing the three products.

Comment: Great, it works. but is it free ware? Because I'm going to use this in my company.   i download EPPlus 3.1.3.zip.  Is this freeware? can i use this in my company?

Comment: It's [LGPL](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/). You can read this [thread](https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/208363). The author says you can use it in your commercial project.

Comment: @ChoiJoseph: My pleasure. Don't forget to accept answers. That's the way SO works. Cheers.

Comment: I have problem with TypeConverter.TryConvert. It said no such method in TypeConverter System.ComponentModel.dll. Is it self defined?

Comment: @user585440: `TypeConverter` has its own class. Did you restore all the packages ?

Comment: What package? I use VS 2010 "(.net 4) System.ComponentModel.

Comment: @user585440: this is the [TypeConverter](https://github.com/Leftyx/ConvertCsvToExcel/blob/master/ConvertCsvToExcel/TypeConverter.cs).

Comment: For what it's worth, I have had a lot of trouble with NPOI. It's ported from a Java library called POI. So, most of the documentation and SO questions are about POI. Sometimes the code is similar but often the Java solution is a completely different method which is frustrating. So far EPPLUS has been much better.

Comment: FYI for anyone using this answer, EPPlus does now have a cost for commercial use: https://www.epplussoftware.com/en/LicenseOverview/

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for the info. fixed and updated the link. Maybe the sample won't work :-s

Comment: big thanks to OP for the NPOI code.  Regarding the TypeConverter linked, in .net core I was getting an error that it couldn't convert object to double.  I changed the TypeConverter signature to return dynamic instead of object and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to proceed with OpenXML then you can follow this.

install the nuget package

```
Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml -Version 2.11.3
```

Read the CSV file yourself as a text file (Example from above answer):

```
private IEnumerable<string[]> ReadCsv(string fileName, char delimiter = ';')
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName, Encoding.UTF8).Select(a => a.Split(delimiter));
    return (lines);
}
```

OpenXML code:

```
private bool ConvertWithOpenXml(string excelFileName, string worksheetName, IEnumerable<string[]> csvLines)
        {
            if (csvLines == null || csvLines.Count() == 0)
            {
                return (false);
            }
            using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFileName, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, true))
            {
                package.AddWorkbookPart();
                package.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                package.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                SheetData xlSheetData = new SheetData();
                foreach (var line in csvLines)
                {
                    Row xlRow = new Row();
                    foreach (var col in line)
                    {
                        Cell xlCell = new Cell(new InlineString(new Text(col.ToString()))) { DataType = CellValues.InlineString };
                        xlRow.Append(xlCell);
                    }
                    xlSheetData.Append(xlRow);
                }
                package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet = new Worksheet(xlSheetData);
                package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet.Save();

            
                // create the worksheet to workbook relation
                package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().AppendChild(new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = package.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(package.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()),

                    SheetId = 1,

                    Name = worksheetName

                });

                package.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
            }
            return (true);
        }
```

Comment: +1 for using the OpenXml library from Microsoft - the syntax isn't as bad as I would have expected.  This should be the accepted answer rather than one that involves a 3rd party package that just wraps the Microsoft package.

Answer (score -1):

At the top of your file insert the following line:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

This will include the namespace needed to use the XlFileFormat and XlSaveAsAccessMode classes. 
If this does not work you may need to add a reference to this DLL to your project as well.

The Close method takes in the following arguments:

1. SaveChanges
2. Filename
3. RouteWorkbook

The documentation for that is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.close(v=office.15).aspx).

Hope that helps.