# how to read the data from blob storage and access it by using azure function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime, timer-trigger, azure-function-async

I have a CSV file in my Blob Storage and I need to **trigger** it every day So I am using **timer trigger**  in azure function app I am able to get the Csv file Data in my azure function-app

- how to read and write the CSV-file data
  and store it in **.xlsx file**
- should I need to Use bindings I am new to this Concept please guide me on this with some Examples

**My function App:**

```
public static class Function1`
{
   
  [FunctionName("Function1")]

    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
       
        try
        {
          
            var ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
            // Setup the connection to the storage account
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
            // Connect to the blob storage
            CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Connect to the blob container
            CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("csvfile");
            // Connect to the blob file
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("empchange.csv");
            // Get the blob file as text
            string contents = blob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;

           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the CSV file renewed everyday ? If so, you could also use a BlobTrigger, and then you could use bindings and save yourself the extra lines of accessing the storage account, the container and then the blob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to read and write the CSV-file data and store it in .xlsx file

If you want to read and write CSV files, you need to install `CsvHelper` NuGet.

`CsvHelper` has many examples for you to learn how to [read](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/) and [write](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/) csv files. I wrote a code sample for reading csv files for you.

**Excel Data**

```
Id,Name,Age
1,2,3
```

**Code Sample**

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            try
            {
                var ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
                // Setup the connection to the storage account
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
                // Connect to the blob storage
                CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                // Connect to the blob container
                CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("csvfile");
                // Connect to the blob file
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("empchange.csv");
                
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                    {
                        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
                        foreach (Foo item in records)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }


    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

As for converting the csv file into `.xlsx` file, I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648641/c-sharp-convert-csv-to-xls-using-existing-csv-file), it should be able to solve your problem.

> should I need to Use bindings I am new to this Concept please guide me on this with some Examples

You can use binding, but your approach can achieve the same purpose. I don't think you need to change your approach. You can learn Binding concept from the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings).

Comment: How would you do the equivalent to write back to blob storage?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //downloads blob's content to a stream
                blockBlobReference.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                //puts the byte arrays to a string
                text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
```